# Change textview accessibility text programmatically

Tags: android, text, textview, accessibility

I am setting .setContentDescription(text) of text-view to a different text as my text in text-view contains HTML tags and accessibility is pronouncing the HTML tags also. I want to put different accessibility text which does not contains html tags. But setting .setContentDescription(text) does not help.

I know that .setContentDescription(text) only works with Views who do not have textual representation e.g. Image Button, but is there any way to change textview's accessibility text?

Thanks

Comment: setContentDescription() also works for views without visual representation, so it also works for TextView. Could you show your code and where you're setting the content description?